# Which side are these washers supposed to go?

Tags: bolts, washer, self-assembly-furniture

I’m trying to assemble this trolly and the instructions are blatantly useless. Attempting to check it from the box picture, I was convinced that the washer goes on the nut side, but as I tried fitting one caster without even tightening it hard, I got a feeling that the railing got a bit crooked (it will be under load pressure) as the caster base isn’t wide enough and that if the washer goes to the inner side, it would provide more support to prevent the caster based wedge int the railing and bend it, but then the front and back heights won’t be the same, since the front side doesn’t have washers. I know we’re speaking about a few millimeters but still.
[image: bolts, nuts and washers]

[image: washers and nuts]

[image: the railing]

[image: box imagine]

[image: manual]
So which side do you think it should go?

Comment: They go on the same side as the nut

Comment: looks like the U channel is not supposed to be where you put it

Comment: I agree with @dk79 the washer normally goes on the same side as the nut this spreads out the force of the nut and makes better contact keeping the force even where if the nut was in the Chanel there is nothing on that side keeping the plate from flexing.

Comment: @EdBeal but when I do that the wheel plate is wedging into that railing and bending it apart...?

Comment: Are you overnighting it? I cannot make out the detail on your instructions page but a single washer I would expect to go under the nut.

Comment: @EdBeal the instructions are horrible and useless!

Comment: The bolts are barely into the nuts, but any reasonable design would have them going all the way through and with some threads slightly past the plastic keeper on the nuts. It is probably assembled wrong.

Comment: I cannot see the washers anywhere in the diagrams. Try assembling without them. They definitely do not go right under the nuts. If they go anywhere it would be *inside* the channel beam.

Comment: @JimStewart basically none of the assembly stems are in the diagram. It only explains how to fold/unfold the trolly and lock/unlock the wheels.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the U-channel on that side came bent - If you compare it to the other side it seems to be bent quite a bit, judging from the pictures.  This is why the caster plate isn't hitting the other side, and why you though to put the washers behind the plate.  However, the washers are meant to go underneath the nut, not the plate.  I would suggest trying to bend the channel back into shape - try using a hammer and a block of wood - place the block of wood on the side of the channel, and then whack the block of wood with the hammer.  The block should help to minimize any distortion as you bend it back.

Comment: The channel got bent as I tried to assemble it. The other side that’s not bent has the same problem that the plate wedges into it when I sit it without the washer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this product is poorly designed/built.

AS noted the washer goes between the nut and the caster plate.

Since the U channel is cheap and bending i would go to the hardware store and buy 16 larger washers (*one for each bolt*). They should be about a 1/4 of an inch, or more, wider that the U channel but have the appropriate size  hole for the bolt.

Put the new larger washers between the caster plate and the U channel.

If the U channel still wants to splay outwards you can drill a hole through it sideways and install machine bolts, nuts, washers to hold it together, then tighten down your caster nuts.